# Document Preview with a pop-up

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am using REST to pull documents from an in-house file-storage system.
As a response I get back the image as binary data. I can do some parsing, get the data as a blob and then encode it to a string which gives me the base64 representation.

The problem is that I don't want to save that image in the system as an attachment, document or a chatter file.

I want to use the base64 value to preview the data using the browser itself.
Basically a user will click a small button or a link which will display a preview of the image in a popup without downloading it locally.

Is that even possible? I've not been able to find an answer at all for the past two days.

Comment: Did you see this- [How can I display a blob as pdf on a visualforce page?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000044612&type=1) It uses iFrame though.

Comment: This won't do, I'll need real preview like Google Document Preview for example but that can take base64 strings instead of URLs.

Comment: Your title currently says "without Visualforce". Can you go into detail about why you want to avoid using Visualforce? I can think of one way to avoid Visualforce (onclick javascript button), but that won't work in Lightning (which Salesforce continues to push pretty hard for everyone to start using). I'd say Visualforce is probably the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Well in reality I don't really care if its built on a Visualforce page, as long it can preview the files in a pop-up without too much work. I don't really want to rebuild a whole document viewer from scratch. The files I get are not limtied to images but csv,xls,docs,pdfs etc

Comment: @KostadinStoev and why do you want to avoid iframes?

Comment: Images would be easy enough (embedding Base64 data into a plain, old `<img>` tag is easy and widely supported). Supporting everything else (csv, xls, doc, pdf, etc...) requires a viewer of some sort.

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't want to display them inline but as popups. Think of it as a file explorer of some sort.

Comment: have a popup page which has a iFrame containing the PDF blob?

Comment: Does it work for PDF only? I've tried it with some other files and it didn't work